# back button not working properly (chrome)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a request axios(vue):

```
.then(response => {
  history.pushState(null, null, response.request.responseURL);
}
```

Standart URL - `http://localhost:30/shop`. With this line, I complete the URL. in the end it will look like: `http://localhost:30/shop?tags[]=5`

But when I go to another page (`http://localhost:30/shop/parts/2123` ) and then click the `back button`. Then I see not the page, but the response of the request (just text).

How i can resolve this problem?

**upd:** with FF working fine. Only when using google chrome.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "only the response of the request"?

Comment: white page with text {"items":[{"id":9947679,"name":something}...

Answer (score 1):

What `history.pushState` does is change the value of the URL in the search bar and push a new URL to browser history; it does not change anything in the DOM. The browser doesn't take "screenshots" of your current page state, so when you go back it only changes the URL on the address bar and the history, but no UI changes.

Based on your code an post, I believe you wanted to redirect the user, which is done easily with:

```js
window.location.href = response.request.responseURL;
```

#### Edit

Based on your comment, you can use `history.replaceState` instead of `pushState`, which won't add changes to history, thus not breaking the back button:

```js
history.replaceState(null, null, response.request.responseURL);
```

Comment: No, I'm using ``history.pushState`` to add GET params to the URL without reloading. But when the user on the page clicks on the product (the link goes to another page with the product, as I indicated), he gets to a new page, clicks "back", then there is no layout, but only the response text

Comment: @Alex see my edit.

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: @Alex back button still not working? That's strange; it works for me. Are you sure you saved the file and am viewing the latest version of your code in your browser?

Comment: Yes I am sure. :) Maybe I didn't explain it that way. I have a page (with a filter), on which I use ``history.statePush`` to add GET parameters to the url without reloading. Next, when on the page with the filter, click on the product and go to the product page(this is another page). And click "back" on the product page, then the URL need is returned (which was in the filter), but on the page instead of layout - axios answer

Comment: such a bug only with  ``response.request.responseURL``, if put any line, for example, '/test', then everything works fine